# MP3 Title in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, mp3

I'm trying to get the title of an MP3 which is in the properties. For example the file name is "iasn_E_052" but the song title is "Guard Your Heart". Getting the file name is easy but the song title is I don't know how. I'm using vb.net visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata like title or artist is stored as [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) in the file.
You need to read the file bytewise and convert the specific bytes to string.
For example the ID3v1 tag is stored in the last 128 bytes of the file. The first three bytes are "TAG" and the next 30 bytes are the title.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO

Class MP3Tags
    Sub GetTitle(filename As String)
        Dim buffer(30) As Byte
        Dim reader As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim length = reader.Length
        If (length > 128) Then
            reader.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End)
            reader.Read(buffer, 0, 3)
            Dim tag As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer, 0, 3)
            If (tag = "TAG") Then
                reader.Read(buffer, 0, 30)
                Dim title As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer, 0, 30)
                Console.WriteLine("Title = " + title)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't contain ID3v1 tags")
            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("File is too short to have tags")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

(based on this [class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5590/Reading-and-writing-MP-ID-v-tags))